# WCF Service wtih Stream response

Tags: wcf, stream

I have a WCF service and one of the method returns Stream.
Now the question is while I try to consume that Stream object, am I trying to use the stream over the network or the client had received the full stream on its own side?

Will it make any difference if I would have used RESTful instead of WCF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of using the streaming interface in WCF is that the client gets a stream from which it can read blocks of bytes. The whole return object (file, picture, video) will **NOT** be assembled in full on the server and sent back as once huge chunk, instead, the client can retrieve chunks at a time from the stream returned from the WCF service.

Your client gets back a "Stream" instance, from which it can then read the data, like from a FileStream or a MemoryStream. That way, the amount of memory needed at any given time is reduced to a manageable size (instead of potentially multiple gigabytes in the buffered mode, you'll transfer a large file in e.g. 1 MB chunks or something like that).

Marc

Comment: should i be using any specific binding when returning Stream back?

Comment: Depends - are you internally, behind a corporate firewall? Then I'd recommend netTcp. Do you need to support external (internet) clients? Then basicHttp is your choice.

Comment: Do we  need to close the stream ? if yes will it be accessible at the client?

Comment: The client will need to close the stream after it's done reading it.

Comment: i am closing the stream at the client end but if i try to delete that image with File.Delete it says 'currently in use by other proecess'.